# Limited Sum in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, rows, octave

Hi lets say  that i have matrix size 5x5.

```
B=[1 2 3 4 5; 10 20 30 40 50; 100 200 300  400 500; 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000; 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000];
```

How do i use function sum, to sum rows between 2 and 4 and have result:

```
A = [1110;2220;3330;4440]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find some useful information about matrix indexing in the documentation at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html

To illustrate your example, you can use B(2:4,:) to retreive the following:

```
ans =
          10          20          30          40          50
          100         200         300         400         500
          1000        2000        3000        4000        5000
```

You can then use the sum function as follows to achieve your desired result:

```
A = sum(B(2:4,:))
```

I hope this helps!

All the best,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

```
MATLAB>> sum(B(2:4,1:4))

ans =

        1110        2220        3330        4440
```

If you want to transpose the result, add `'` at the end.